# В каком месте правильно установить функцию? Как правильно зациклить код, с 17 строки по 27?

Tags: функции, циклы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как зациклить данную функцию?
И как сделать её в виде функции?
Вот задание: "Напишите функцию, которая принимает два списка и выводит все элементы первого,
которых нет во втором."
Вот то, что у меня получилось:

```
a = ['A', '8', '3', 'V', '5']
print (a)
b = ['A', '3', '5', '3', '9']
print (b)
c = len(a)-1
d = len(b)-1
print(c, d)
x = 0
p = 0
for i in range(0, d):
         if b[i] == a[c]:
             x = x+1  
print('Символ %s встречается во второй строке %s раз' %(a[c], x))
if x > 0:
   del a[c] 
   #d = d-1 
   c = c-1
else: 
   i = 0
   c = c-1       
print('Символы первой строки, которые не встречаются во второй: ')
print(a)
```

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ниже реализовал искомую функцию `f()` в самом простом виде.

Если нужна скорость, то раскомментируйте строку `#b = set(b)`, это позволит быстрее искать внутри массива `b`. Если нужна простота то удалите строку `#b = set(b)`, будет работать просто медленней, например если это задача на первых начальных уроках изучения Питона то может ещё использование `set()` не изучается.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##NYmxCgIxEET7fMWAxSaQLggqWPgTNkeKC@5imuSIa@HXx8udTvGYN7N89FlL6P3BArGzR3IXgzWHhCterDa5zRvruxVMDKkNjFwwI8vaStVhKRqztFzUip3oRh50GggD94EjRY/fFfbh384Unev9Cw)

```
def f(a, b):
    #b = set(b)
    return [e for e in a if e not in b]

print(f(['A', '8', '3', 'V', '5'], ['A', '3', '5', '3', '9']))
```

Вывод:

```
['8', 'V']
```

Если доработать именно ваш код и алгоритм, то получится следующее.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##dZLNaoNAFIX38xRnE8ahBhKk0AYs9CW6ERdKtDWICcaF3aVuugi0z9A3CIHQ9M@@wp0nMjNqrS5ywcPcuec4H8ysHrOHZWJV1TwIERqeCV/MGFR5sBFH68zwRN2HyxQRogSpl9wHRhwkaoIxpibG9dfmdOUqO@k6nVwMk77ouXVFITwncmHb8J2FOxw2v7ywMe22V2mUZAanNzrSN@2ppC@M1qC9fJKF3NBBPtNOaaH6V2iDnhVUqllJH2htJX3SQQfVekfvHCMYmsNELgTrweW4wWRINQ/ihpmdAZJb0K9i2NTt4MyjCaVlAyS3ioF@tAzw5cs5/Bm46J2qbojp63L4LTfBr7RYWu60XHKXdT7/32Y1w7/VdWfzBWtfAquqEw)

```
def f(a, b):
    a = list(a)
    for i in range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1):
        x = 0
        for j in range(len(b)):
            if a[i] == b[j]:
                x += 1
        print('Символ %s встречается во второй строке %s раз' % (a[i], x))
        if x > 0:
            del a[i] 
    print('Символы первой строки, которые не встречаются во второй: ')
    print(a)

a = ['A', '8', '3', 'V', '5']
print(a)
b = ['A', '3', '5', '3', '9']
print(b)
f(a, b)
```

Вывод:

```
['A', '8', '3', 'V', '5']
['A', '3', '5', '3', '9']
Символ 5 встречается во второй строке 1 раз
Символ V встречается во второй строке 0 раз
Символ 3 встречается во второй строке 2 раз
Символ 8 встречается во второй строке 0 раз
Символ A встречается во второй строке 1 раз
Символы первой строки, которые не встречаются во второй: 
['8', 'V']
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!
Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: @SlavaKuznetsov Пожалуйста! :)

Comment: @DarkLord Кстати если ответ мой выше подходящий для вас и верный, то не забудьте принять его и добавить +1 голос. Это можно сделать в самом верху моего ответа слева от него, там птичка для принятия ответа как верного и стрелка вверх для +1 голоса.